# Can jQuery select elements with IDs that start similarly?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have multiple comment ids I want to reset to a default value.

Ex:

```
<a id="comments_inner_toggle_45">example 1</a>
<a id="comments_inner_toggle_608">example 2</a>
<a id="comments_inner_toggle_28">example 3</a>
...
```

How can I write the correct tag in jQuery to select every tag with an id of "comments_inner_toggle_" and perform some operation on it?

I think it's something similar to:

```
$('a[id|=comments_inner_toggle_]').whatever
```

This is wrong however because the code above will only match the tag with "comments_inner_toggle_" and not with a number appended at the end.  How can I fix this?  thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$('a[id^=comments_inner_toggle_]').whatever`

The caret selector means begin with. | means contains or starts with and has a hyphen. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/